# Is it possible to run two different animations on one SVG element?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm using Snap.svg to do this animation. Basically, I want to rotate an element around a point but I want the element to still face the same way when it's rotating. Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/mabotofu/MpEu4/6/

```
<svg id="test">
  <circle transform="translate(200,200)" r="10" fill="transparent" stroke="#aaa" />
  <g>
    <circle cx="0" cy="50" r="10" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="150" r="10" />
    <text x="0" y="100" fill="red">TEST</text>
  </g>
</svg>

var paper = Snap(test),
container = paper.select("g");

container
    .attr({
        fill: "transparent",
        stroke: "#aaa",
        transform: "translate(200,200)"
    })
    .animate({
        transform: "t200,200r720,0,0"
    }, 6000);
```

In this example, I need the "TEST" text to still stay horizontally even when it's rotating.
toransform="rotate()" is already applied to the element so I can't use rotate again on the lement but I don't know how I can rotate around the center point then also rotate the text itself so it stays horizontally. Please help! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the rotation in the opposite direction to the text element:

```
...
container = paper.select("g");
text = container.select("text");
...
text.animate({transform: "t0,0r-720"}, 6000);
```

See: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/MpEu4/7/)

Comment: It seems kind of unbalanced, but it's because the text is aligned by the top-left corner. In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/MpEu4/8/) I adjusted the baseline a bit and centered it.

Comment: I'm so sorry, somehow I didn't see your answer. I know it's a long time ago but I appreciate it. I ended up doing something similar. This is the site. fltr.io
Thank you for your help!